# Access let- variable on ng-template in custom directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'd like to be able to access the `let-*` variables I'm defining on an `ng-template` using my own custom directive which is on the ng-template itself.

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate 
             let-dataItem 
             let-column="column" 
             myDirective [directiveColumn]="column">
    {{someInput}}
</ng-template>
```

What I try to achieve is to pass the `let-column` value into my custom directive as an input. Is that possible at all or am I only able to use the `let-*` inside the ng-template?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I‘d like to use the „column“ property in my „myDirective“ to set some styling on it.

Comment: What about `[myDirective]="column"`?

Comment: I‘ve tried that but it‘s always undefined. Also it‘s the same as with another @input as I understand.

Comment: Can you create a demo on stackblitz?